# How do you kick a benign user off your system?

Tags: users, administration

I was googling this a bit ago and noticed a couple of ways, but I'm guessing that google doesn't know all. So how do *you* kick users off your Linux box? also how do you go about seeing they are logged in in the first place? and related... does your method work if the user is logged into an X11 DE (not a requirement I'm just curious)?

Comment: Changed question to reflect assumptions given the accepted answer.  In the context of a security breach, the only way to kick a malicious user off your system is to be much smarter than that user.  A clever user is not going to let themselves show up in utmp or get found by something as trivial as `who(1)` or `w(1)`.  The only foolproof way to get rid of any potential rootkits that may be installed is to completely wipe and reinstall the system.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

There's probably an easier way, but I do this:

1. See who's logged into your machine -- use `who` or `w`:

   ```
   > who  
   mmrozek  tty1         Aug 17 10:03  
   mmrozek  pts/3        Aug 17 10:09 (:pts/2:S.0)
   ```
2. Look up the process ID of the shell their TTY is connected to:

   ```
   > ps t  
   PID   TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND  
   30737 pts/3    Ss     0:00 zsh
   ```
3. Laugh at their impending disconnection (this step is optional, but encouraged)

   ```bash
   > echo "HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA" | write mmrozek pts/3
   ```
4. Kill the corresponding process:

   ```
   > kill -9 30737
   ```

---

I just discovered you can combine steps 1 and 2 by giving `who` the `-u` flag; the PID is the number off to the right:

```
> who -u
mmrozek  tty1         Aug 17 10:03 09:01        9250
mmrozek  pts/18       Aug 17 10:09 01:46       19467 (:pts/2:S.0)
```

Comment: kill sends a signal to a process, with -9 indicating a 'kill' signal. You can see a list of all signals with `man kill` or http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?kill - +1 for the evil laughter :-)

Comment: +1 for "Laugh at their impending disconnection (this step is optional, but encouraged)"

Comment: `kill -9`, huh?  You really are in BOFH mode on this one.

Comment: @Jander You're kicking a user off the system; how nice do you need to be?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: I like your answer. Can this be simulated on a home linux laptop in this way: creating a new user and logging in as new user from a different shell and then proceed with the above steps in another shell?

Comment: @KishorNanda Sure? I'm not sure why you'd kick yourself off the system, but yes, it's the same procedure

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: No, I am not talking about kicking myself off. Let's say I am logged in as `me`. I will create a user `test` from `shell1` and login as `test` in `shell1`. Since I did not physically logoff, I am still logged in as `me`. So I will open `shell2` and follow your steps to view who's logged. This will show `me` and `test`. Then I wish to kick user `test` off with your steps. I hope it makes sense. :-)

Comment: @KishorNanda Right, I realize it's a different user, but `test` is still you in real life, so you're using your first account to kick off your second account. Which works fine, but is kind of strange

Comment: Normally, I'd say [don't encourage people to abuse `kill -9`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8916/9537), and [start with gentler signals](http://stackoverflow.com/q/690415/855954) instead, but I suppose in this context it doesn't matter so much.  I am just leaving a comment in case people miss the joke.

Comment: There is also [slay](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=slay&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+6.0+squeeze&format=html&locale=en) which basically automates the whole process (even making fun of your victim if you enable butthead mode)

Answer (score 40):

As Micheal already pointed out, you can use `who` to find out who's logged in. However if they have multiple processes, there's a more convenient way than killing each process individually: you can use `killall -u username` to kill all processes by that user.

Comment: +1. Using `killall` will also be slightly more appropriate in graphical environments, since there's more than just a shell to kill.

Comment: WARNING: If you use this for root user you will kill all root processes and you will need to physically restart the server.

Comment: @Kunok under what situtation would you want kick the root user off the machine?  Like if that account got hijacked or something?

Answer (score 25):

Necromancy!

I appreciate the humor of the accepted answer, but professionally I can't advocate it.

The most graceful method I'm aware of is to send a -HUP to the shell to simulate a user hangup. You can send this to the user's idle sshd to simulate their connection being lost, which triggers a cleanup of the entire shell environment (including child shells), or send this to specific nested shells (say, ones setting inside of a disconnected terminal multiplexer that are keeping you from unmounting a filesystem) if you want to be really precise.

Using `write` to send messages to terminally idle ptys before you boot them **is** a fun hobby though.

Comment: While the pseudo-omnipotent feeling that accompanies a kill -9 is fun, this suggestion is probably better.  An up-vote from me.

Comment: To make this answer explicit, what I did was:

    `echo "Hasta la vista, baby" | write user_name pty_name && sleep 30 && killall -u user_name -HUP`(the sleep gives the user the chance to save and log off, but you're probably only using this on a user who forgot to log off anyway)

Answer (score 13):

Logout the user 'username':

```
skill -KILL -u username
```

See `man skill`

Comment: I think that will kill *all* processes by that user, not just their shell, but if that's what you want then this is definitely simpler

Comment: I don't really see this working on RHEL7

Answer (score 11):

Other useful command is `pkill` here `pkill -u username && pkill -9 -u username`.
`killall` have disadvantage that on Solaris IIRC it means something completely different - also `pkill` have slightly more advanced options.

Comment: On Solaris 'killall' is used by the shutdown scripts to kill (nearly) all the processes on the server. "It does what it says on the tin."

Comment: Folks, why do you fancy SIGKILL so much? Running programs and application won't even have a chance to save data and clean up a bit. SIGTERM (as is used  at shutdown) or SIGHUP will do as well and is way more graceful. (You can still send SIGKILL after expiry of a grace period.)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this indicates a larger problem.  If you have users that you don't trust on your system, you should probably level it and re-image.

With that in mind, you can do some or all of the following:

```
# set up the environment
BADUSER=foo # where foo is the username in question
USERLINE=$(grep '^${BADUSER}:' /etc/passwd)
BADUID=$(echo ${USERLINE} | awk -F: '{print $3}')
BADGID=$(echo ${USERLINE} | awk -F: '{print $4}')
BADHOMEDIR=$(echo ${USERLINE} | awk -F: '{print $6}')
BDIR="~/backup/home-backup/"
TSTAMP=$(date +%F)
TAR_FILENAME="${BADUSER}-${TSTAMP}.tar.bz2"
OWNED_FILENAME="${BADUSER}-files-${TSTAMP}.txt"

# disable the user's future login
sudo chsh -s /bin/false "${BADUSER}"

# kill all of the user's processes
BADPROCS=$(ps auwx | grep '^${BADUSER} ' | awk '{print $2}')
sudo kill -9 ${BADPROCS}

# back up/clear the user's home directory
mkdir -p ${BDIR}
sudo tar -cfj ${BDIR}/${TAR_FILENAME} ${BADHOMEDIR}
sudo rm -rf ${BADHOMEDIR}/.* ${BADHOMEDIR}/*

# find all files owned by user
sudo find / -user ${BADUSER} > ~/backup/${OWNED_FILENAME}

# remove user
sudo userdel ${BADUSER}
```

Comment: I don't know that I would agree with "level it an reimage" this is unix not windows... I don't really have this problem... I was just asking.

Comment: Plus, just because you have to kick a user off doesn't necessarily mean they're untrustworthy. Maybe they just forgot to log out.

Comment: xenoterracide: Maybe I'm just protective of the systems I maintain, but if I had a user who I felt needed to be forcibly removed from a system under my control, something serious would have had to have happened.

Comment: -1 for reading things into the question that don't logically follow and dragging the Q/A off-topic.

Comment: `you have users that you don't trust on your system` ...Or it could just be that you're killing one as a message to the others. After all, is the sysadmin's creed not "It is better to be feared than to be loved"? All jokes aside, Machiavelli should write an O'Reilly book.

Answer (score 0):

I looked all around and could not find a single script to automate this task.

So, based on the solutions proposed here I mixed everything in [an interactive Bash script](https://github.com/tavinus/kick.sh) that lists the users and sessions from `who -u` for the user to choose what to do.

You can then either:

- kill all sessions for a user

  `killall -u <username> -HUP`
- kill a specific session

  `kill <PID>`

All the required information comes from `who -u` and is then parsed using `mapfile` and `awk`.

I will add the possibility to send a message using `write` later (forking the process with a delay).

I will probably add the option to kill a specific session with `kill -9` as well. But I had no problems with just `kill` and as pointed by others, `kill -9` should be avoided if possible.

You can check the code on github if you want to try it or learn more about how I am doing it in an automated way:

- https://github.com/tavinus/kick.sh

Answer (score 0):

> So how do you kick [benign] users off your Linux box?

In the end it comes down to identifying and ending those processes that are owned, associated, or spawned from a user-id.  Whatever commands you use to get to that end goal doesn't necessarily matter as long as you get there.

Basically two answers...

**Option A:**  causing a log out of said user, for which ever and however many logins they have.  So this would mean identifying those processes that are owned by a user, traceable by uid, and classified as part of some login process for the given linux distro you are running.  Realize there are parent processes such as SSH or VNC before the "login" and child processes such as GDM after the "login"   Usually killing a parent process will kill the child process, but not always.  So you would want to kill these other processes that are obviously no longer needed after the log out.  In doing all this, this would keep background jobs running... because it's a benign user and maybe you just want to log them out.  As far as i know, `/usr/bin/w` and `/usr/bin/who` will report who has passed through the log in process.

**option B:**  end all processes owned by a specific uid completely, which would simply mean killing any and all processes owned by said user, this would also log them out if they are logged in.  This would satisfy the *kick them off the system*.  That only needs to be a simple `ps -ef | grep <uid>` and then ending all those processes in whatever manner is acceptable.

fwiw in SLES 11 it reports

> man skill
>   ...  These tools are probably obsolete and unportable. The command syntax is poorly defined. Consider using the killall, pkill, and pgrep  commands instead.

`kill -9` FTW !

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, it is not really useful to use `killall -u username` because if it is the same user as you, you will kick yourself off. So `kill` the process will be a better solution.

Comment: also if there are processes run by that user, perhaps SSHD you will never come into the Server, cause SSH shutdown.

Comment: *Why on Earth* would the SSH daemon (or *any* daemon) be running using the credentials of a user that needs to be forcibly logged off the system for any realistic reason whatsoever? Also, what does this answer add that is not covered by [Michael Mrozek's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/622/2465) or [Andrew B's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60591/2465) (and possibly others)?

Answer (score -2):

This command worked great for the GUI my "significant" refuses to sign out of...

```
leaves@me:/# skill -HUP -u username
```

- I don't know what happened.
- There must have been an update.
- The "Google" was down again.
- It was a virus on the InterWebs.

Some diversions in case you need them.

Comment: This is already mentioned in bsd’s answer.