# `[java] <defunct>` with defunct children -> Any way to collect them?

Tags: process, kill, process-management, init, thread

Relating to question : [What if 'kill -9' does not work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5642/what-if-kill-9-doesnt-work)

I have following situation : *zombie process with threads, not collected by init* :

```
[root@Arch64]# ps auxH | grep java
gwpl       569  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Zl   04:23   0:00 [java] <defunct>
gwpl       569  5.5 49.0 1466648 375572 ?      Rl   07:25  23:55 [java] <defunct>
gwpl       569 16.0 49.0 1466648 375572 ?      Rl   12:27  20:54 [java] <defunct>
gwpl       569 17.9 49.0 1466648 375572 ?      Rl   12:47  19:48 [java] <defunct>
root     10466  0.0  0.0   6740   628 pts/0    S+   14:38   0:00 grep java
[root@Arch64]# pstree -s 569
init---java---3*[{java}]
```

Can I do anything about that ?

Or is it *init* bug as suggested in comment to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11173/9689 ?

If it's a bug, what should I dump to help fixing it?

---

Above listing uses following status codes: `Zl`, `Rl`, `S+`. Here is cheatsheet from `man ps` to decode them:

```
PROCESS STATE CODES
       (...)
       R    Running or runnable (on run queue)
       S    Interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
       (...)
       Z    Defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent.

       For BSD formats and when the stat keyword is used, additional characters may be displayed:
       (...)
       L    has pages locked into memory (for real-time and custom IO)
       (...)
       +    is in the foreground process group
```

Comment: If `init` doesn't collect its (adopted) children, it's a bug in `init`.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably too late to do any good, but I have to wonder whether maybe process 569 *isn't* entirely a zombie.  Maybe this is what you get on this OS (which OS is it?) when the initial thread has terminated but other threads are still running.  If that's the case, `kill(1)` should still be effective.  If it isn't, the next thing I would try is using [`tgkill(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/tgkill), or your OS's equivalent, on the threads listed in R-state (this will require you to write some C, as there probably aren't canned shell utilities to invoke those system calls).

Also, attempting to attach `strace` or `gdb` to the process may reveal something useful for diagnosis.

A bug in `init`'s reaping of zombies is extraordinarily unlikely; if this is a bug, I would say it is more likely to be a *kernel* bug in which multithreaded processes are (under some conditions) not properly disposed of.

Comment: At least in Linux, threads are just kernel tasks, just like regular one-thread processes. Sure, there might be a glitch in handling them, but it is *extremely* unlikely. Zombies are the result of parents not handling the exit of their children; haven't *ever* seen a different reason.

Answer (score 1):

[Init always waits,](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11172/how-can-i-kill-a-defunct-process-whose-parent-is-init) goes the old saying. So a bug in the kernel is rather unlikely. What is the ppid of process 569? `ps -alef` would give you that, or, if you are of the BSD persuasion, `ps axo stat,pid.ppid,comm`. If the parent is not init, 569 is probably an [ordinary Zombie.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) And as zombies are only dangerous when there's a lot of them, you can just let this one stand in the corner and have the next reboot dispose of it.