# How to find source of spawning process?

Tags: process, kill

I have a Java process running on a RedHat Linux instance.

The problem is it keeps reappearing after I kill it. I am not sure where to look. I've already went to crontab, but no luck.

I've looked at the PPID, but it points to init (1).

Any idea how I can find out the source?

Comment: Can you give us something to go on? Does the process write to any files for example? Can you show us the output of `ps xf` showing the process tree? As it stands, we have very little to go on.

Comment: You said you went to crontab... Have you also checked `at` to see if any of those is the one?.

Comment: Can you tell us what java software you are actually running. I have seen tools like Cassandra, that actually have a built-in watchdog in certain setups that just fires up another instance of the database once the first instance failed (was not gracefully stopped).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a number of possibilities (some mentioned in other answers):

1. A system or user cronjob executing often,
2. In SysV init, an `/etc/inittab` entry for the service with the `respawn` directive,
3. In systemd, a unit file with the `Restart` option set to a value other than `no`,
4. In Upstart, a service configuration file with the `respawn` directive,
5. A process monitoring tool such as [`monit`](http://mmonit.com/monit/#about), or
6. An ad-hoc watchdog process for that particular service.

An interesting new (linux-only) tool that could provide more insight into where the process is being started is [sysdig](http://www.sysdig.org/).

Sysdig uses the Linux Kernel's tracepoint features to provide what amounts to a fast, system wide `strace`.

For example, if I wanted to see every process starting `ls`, I can issue:

```
sudo sysdig evt.type=execve and evt.arg.exe=ls
```

When `ls` is run somewhere, I will get a message like this:

```
245490 16:53:54.090856066 3 ls (10053) < execve res=0 exe=ls args=--color=auto. tid=10053(ls) pid=10053(ls) ptid=9204(bash) cwd=/home/steved fdlimit=1024 pgft_maj=0 pgft_min=37 vm_size=412 vm_rss=4 vm_swap=0 env=...
```

I truncated the environment information returned, but as you can see, in the ptid I can see the name and pid of the program calling execve.  `execve` is the system call used in Linux used to execute new commands (all other exec calls are just frontends to execve).

Comment: sysdig is a great advice! BTW, it's now available for Windows (and Mac, I think) with limited functionality.

Comment: How does monit help here? I started reading through the manual but it looks like an alternative or backup to something like Nagios. I'm not seeing how it would help you track down a respawning process.

Answer (score 11):

I believe you could use `pstree`. You could specify the command as,

```
pstree -p PID
```

The above will give you a list of all parents of the java applications.

Comment: This won't help at all, as the OP already said he looked at the PPID, which is 1.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm, please look at the original question before it was edited. It was not mentioned in the first version of the question.

Comment: sigh. Another poster who makes his question a moving target without marking his edits :(

Answer (score 8):

You could have a look at its PPID (parent process ID) :

```
$ ps -eo pid,ppid,args | grep java
```

Once you've got the PPID (second column) of your Java process, use `ps` again to find the associated process:

```
$ ps -p [PPID]
```

*Edit* : if the parent is 1 (init), then the *first* parent of your Java process died right after "giving birth" (how sad). Because of that, you can't use the current process hierarchy to find it. The first thing I would recommend you to do is to check `ps -ef`. You might find the culprit just by reading the output.

Then, [have a look at crontabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134906/how-do-i-list-all-cron-jobs-for-all-users) (you did it already, but it won't hurt) :

```
$ for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do echo $user; crontab -u $user -l; done
```

<sup>This will require root privileges.</sup>

Still can't see a Java process scheduled? Dang it. Let's try something else. If your Java process is present since boot, have a look at programs scheluded at boot time. I would suggest something like...

```
$ grep -iR java /etc/rc*
```

If you still can't find anything then... Well I admit I'm running out of ideas. You should really have another look at `ps -ef`, and locate processes associated with Java-based programs. You should come across a daemon, or a "launcher", responsible for the constant respawning of your Java process.

Comment: I've tried looking up the parent process, but it just points to init (PPID = 1). I'll modify question with this info.

Comment: @JoseChavez, if your PPID is 1, then the java processes that are getting created are zombie processes.[Check this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588061/killing-a-java-zombie-process).

Comment: @JoseChavez I edited my answer with a few more tracks to investigate in your case.

Comment: @Ramesh If the PPID is 1, they may *or may not* be [zombies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process).  If they were not actually spawned by `init`, they are at least [orphans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process).  The `state` specifier to `ps` will show if they are zombies (e.g., `ps -eo pid,ppid,state,comm`); the state will be `Z`.

Comment: @goldilocks, thanks for the clarification. I appreciate it. :)

Comment: @goldilocks: If the PPID is 1, they _are not zombies_, unless the init process is malfunctioning; it ought to run a wait loop that reaps all orphaned zombies immediately.

Comment: @Ramesh: You probably meant "daemons" rather than "zombies".

Comment: @HenningMakholm I did not mean daemons but right you are -- an orphan cannot become a zombie because it has an (adoptive) parent that will not mishandle it!  Although there looks to be occasional freak exceptions to this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11172/how-can-i-kill-a-defunct-process-whose-parent-is-init

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know who is the parent, you should you some system tracer like [auditd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd)

you'd enable logging with:

```
auditctl -a exit,always -S execve -F path=/usr/bin/rrdtool
```

and then in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` find lines like:

```
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1414027338.620:6232): arch=c000003e syscall=59
success=yes exit=0 a0=7fdea0e4db23 a1=7fffec7c5220 a2=7fffec7c87d0
a3=7fdea1b559d0 items=2 ppid=17176 pid=18182 auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 
euid=1000 suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=pts8 
ses=2 comm="sh" exe="/bin/dash" key=(null)
```

(broken into multiple lines for readibility). You're interested in `exe="/bin/dash"` and/or `pid=18182` which identify your rouge process you want to look for, and `ppid=17176` which identifies parent which executed it.