# How to safely kill processes so that output redirection is not aborted?

Tags: kill

I'm writing some automation scripts, in which I need to kill some processes.

Previously I would usually use `kill -9 pid` to kill processes but once upon a time, I notice that when I used `kill -9` to kill some `tcpdump` processes:

For example:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -w output.pcap
```

The captured packets were not put into `output.pcap` and it was empty. But if I used `kill`, it worked fine.

For some processes, like `./prog >> test_log`, I'm afraid if I use `kill -9` to kill the processes the output won't get redirected to `test_log`.

I'm also afraid if I use `kill` without `-9` the kill command may fail.

Can anyone tell me how to properly use `kill` so that the killing doesn't cause problems with the output file and I'm able to kill the processes without issue?

Answer (score 3):

If a process does not write to a terminal but uses redirection instead (or even when explicitely writing to a file) then buffering may be an issue. Have a look at `stdbuf` and `unbuffer` (`expect`) or search here for them.

Your `tcpdump` problem can be solved (or reduced) by the `-U` flag.

In general you should kill this way:

```
kill $PID; sleep $wait; kill -9 $pid &>/dev/null
```

`kill` / `kill -TERM` gives the process the chance to cleanly finish (including e.g. flushing buffers and closing file descriptors) whereas `kill -KILL` just removes the process from memory and the process list which is always a risk with non-atomic operations which may be in progress right then.

Answer (score 1):

You should start out with issuing a kill order of `15` wait, if not terminated, `kill 2`, etc.

In general, normal running, with exceptions, it is not the best sign if a program does not end after kill 15,2,1. Though you can't expect it to end immediately.

Secondly it depends on the specific program you kill. Some programs catch and clean up, others should have done it but don't, others has nothing to clean up
and leave up for the OS to clean up after it. Etc.

You should also (always) check if there is other signals you can send to the
application or if it is a deamon, by which you usually have a start/stop script etc.

Also see:

- [What if 'kill -9' does not work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5642/what-if-kill-9-does-not-work)
- [Why not kill -9 a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/why-not-kill-9-a-process#8927)