# Closing all Nautilus windows from terminal

Tags: command-line, kill, nautilus

How can I close all opened Nautilus (explorer) windows from the terminal?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
nautilus -q
```

or

```
killall nautilus
```

If `nautilus` is in the middle of doing something you should use the first command as it allows `nautilus` to exit gracefully. The second command just "terminates" `nautilus` so if invoked in the middle of e.g. a copy/move operation you might end up with corrupted data.

Comment: `killall nautilus` didn't work for me (over ssh).

Comment: `nautilus --quit`

Answer (score 5):

```
pkill nautilus
```

Or to kill everything with nautilus in the name, while insisting:

```
pkill -9 -f nautilus
```

Comment: [do not `kill -9`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/why-not-kill-9-a-process)

Comment: The side-effects of kill -9 are no big deal. I agree that the executable should have had a chance to shut down cleanly first, but "do not kill -9" gives associations to parents that want their child to wear a helmet at all times.

Comment: Yeah, not using kill -9 is impractical. In a perfect world, we don't even need to use pkill at all.