# How to stop the executing process in Linux

Tags: linux

I have a script file pingIP.sh which just pings the given IP address,

```
ping -c 70 74.125.228.71
```

The problem is when I try to stop the executed script in the middle its not stopping it properly.

Using linux cmd `ps -ef|grep pingIP |grep -v 'grep pingIP'` I'm able to get the process id, and killing it using cmd `kill -9 processid`.

For example, executing script file

```
PING 74.125.228.71 (74.125.228.71) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 74.125.228.71: icmp_seq=1 ttl=122 time=256 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.228.71: icmp_seq=2 ttl=122 time=244 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.228.71: icmp_seq=3 ttl=122 time=250 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.228.71: icmp_seq=4 ttl=122 time=254 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.228.71: icmp_seq=5 ttl=122 time=243 ms
```

Executing the `kill` command now just stops the script execution but ping response is continuing until specified ping count is reached.

Any suggestions to avoid the ping execution even after stopping the execution of script file?

Comment: Ctrl+c in terminal didn't help?

Comment: Ctrl+c will work in shell.. since im doing the above process using Java, I need linux cmds to do it

Comment: Use `Process.destroy()` if you are doing this from Java.

Comment: [do not `kill -9`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/why-not-kill-9-a-process?lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Usually, one would `Ctrl+C` on the invoking shell / kill the process from the parent process by sending a signal via `Process.destroy()` (Java).

A neat tool for such tasks is `pkill`, which can kill processes by a pattern, e.g.

```
pkill ping
```

Note that a regular user may not kill another users processes, so make sure you are logged in on the right computer with the right user id.

Bonus tip: use `pgrep -fl ping` to list matching processes, to make sure you want to kill all of them - because running as root, `pkill ssh` will *also* kill your `sshd` and may lock you out. So in particular when running as root - which you should avoid anyway - double check with `pgrep`.

Comment: pkill is dangerous sometime. For instance, if you want a to kill a ssh connection, pkill ssh will kill sshd, and kick you out of your server (if you were logged as root).

Comment: Not so much as user, with a safe pattern such as `ping` when you don't know your way around anyway. ;-) But yes, it's best to test with `pgrep` first.

Comment: `pkill ping` kills any process whose process name contains `ping` (more precisely that match the `ping` regular expression). `pkill -x ping` will kill the processes whose process name **is** `ping`, but still that kills all the `ping` processes, not just the one you started.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to kill the shell process and any other process it has spawned, best is probably to start a new process group (`setpgid()` in the child after the `fork()` before running the `execve()` on the script), and kill the process group with `kill(-pid)` where `pid` is the return value of `fork()` in the parent.

If calling `setpgid()` is not an option, you can still do it like:

Instead of:

```
run("your-script its args");
```

Do:

```
run("set -m; trap 'kill %' TERM; your-script its args & wait")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use killall. For ex. "killall scriptname". killall kills a process by name. Additionally you can also issue signal like. SIGKILL, SIGSTOP etc.

Comment: On some systems it really kills all processes.

Answer (score 0):

Get process ID as you've written:

```
ps -ef|grep pingIP |grep -v 'grep pingIP'
```

and then kill children process using

```
pkill -P process-id
```

Comment: Why this **hack** with `grep -v grep`? OUCH. `man pkill`!
(Much smarter solutions have been posted hours ago!)

Comment: Agree but it doesn't matter. I've just copied it from 'sraina' question. pkill -P is the essence.