# kill all process of executables in a folder

Tags: kill

I need to kill all the child process.

The main process in lmbench

```
pkill -9 lmbench
```

is not killing it, but

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

kills the parent process,

but even after killing the parent process some process from /usr/lib/lmbebch/bin keeps running,

**How to kill all process or executables located inside /usr/lib/lmbench ?**

or kill lmbench with its children.

I cannot use ctrl + c as I start it from a shell script and use pipe to control lmbench

---

Solved the problem by using

```
busybox killall -9 lmbench
busybox pkill -P $lmbenchPID
```

but is there any single command way?

lmbenchDriver.sh is the shell script that calls lmbench

so after lmbenchDriver exits, I still can see process

> lmbenchDriver,
>   lembench,
>   mem,
>   line,

Comment: [do not kill -9 if not absolutely necessary](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/why-not-kill-9-a-process)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
pkill -P PPID
```

which should kill all children of parent process with ID = PPID.

Comment: `busybox killall -9 lmbench`

`busybox pkill -P $lmbenchPID`

together solved the problem