# Why is 'kill -9' killing browser as well as server?

Tags: bash, shell-script, kill

I sometimes have to use `kill -9` as a last resort to kill my rails server. Unfortunately, I have to do that often enough that I wrote a helper function in my bash_profile to do it.

If I do it manually -- `ps aux | grep '[r]ails]`, grab the pid (eg. `12345`), and `kill -9 12345` -- it kills the server and leaves the browser intact. But my function kills the browser too, which I don't want to do:

```
function running {
  ps -p $(lsof -i :3000 -t) &> /dev/null
}

function k9 {
  if running
  then
    kill -9 $(lsof -i :3000 -t)
  else
    echo "Rails server is not running"
  fi
}
```

I've confirmed that `lsof -i :3000 -t` grabs the same pid as I'm getting from `ps aux`, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unrelated, but are you sure you need `kill -9`? There are other signals you can try if the default doesn't work.

Comment: @chepner Certainly wish I didn't, but I tried my other options (-15 etc) and the rails server gets truly stuck

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**The problem:**

With `lsof -i :3000 -t`, you will look for any processes connected to a port 3000, which may be on the **remote** side.

In the cases where you use your script, the browser seems to have a connetction to the rails server on port 3000. The difference is in the timing between using the browser and using `kill`.

That means the browser is listed  in the output of `lsof` too, and killed.

You should better kill processes that look like your rails server, not anything that is using a port 3000, locally or elsewhere.

**The general solution:**

**`pkill`** is the **right tool** for the job.
For **trying** what is matched, use `pgrep`, which matches the same way:

If the command line of the server, as shown in ps, starts with a **command name** that identifies your server instance, you can use `pkill servercommand`.
If you need to match a part of the **command line** arguments, add `-f`, like `pkill -f serverargument`.

The processes that are killed by `pkill` will just be listed by `pgrep` - so use that to try what will be killed. Add the option `-a` to `pgrep` to list the command line, instead of the pid only.

**Examples for pgrep / pkill:**

As an example for using `-f`: According to `ps`, these two instances of `xbindkeys` are running:

```
$ ps aux|grep '[x]bindkeys'
26719 ?        S      0:00 xbindkeys -f /tmp/xbindkeysrc-tmp
32046 ?        S      0:00 xbindkeys -f /home/auser/.xbindkeysrc
```

Now I can find both instances with:

```
$ pgrep xbindkeys
26719
32046
```

Or showing the commands:

```
$ pgrep -a xbindkeys
26719 xbindkeys -f /tmp/xbindkeysrc-tmp
32046 xbindkeys -f /home/auser/.xbindkeysrc
```

Or match one of the instances by the command line arguments:

```
$ pgrep -f '/home/auser/.xbindkeysrc'
32046
```

Without `-f`, none of the processes are matched:

```
$ pgrep '/home/auser/.xbindkeysrc'
```

Finally, sending the process a signal, like with `kill`:

```
$ pkill -f '/home/auser/.xbindkeysrc'
```

**Alternative solution based on original approach:**

The solution with `pkill` is much more general, but to follow your original approach, the `lsof` command can be made **more strict** to match
"any local server listening on the port",
instead of
"any program using the local port in any way, or using a remote port of that number in any way".

The option `-sTCP:LISTEN` restricts the list to ports listening on, and, as only local ports can be listened on, also to local ports only.

It could be used as a `if` test like this:

```
if lsof -i :3000 -sTCP:LISTEN -t >/dev/null ; then
    echo running
else
    echo not running
fi
```

---

**Side note on using SIGKILL, as in kill -9:**

The KILL signal can be used with `pkill` just the same way as with `kill`:

```
$ pkill -9 -f '/home/auser/.xbindkeysrc'
```

But in most general cases, that has no advantage above the default signal `-15`, and in some cases, it breaks things. So it's not a good idea to make it a habit.

Take a look at [When should I not kill -9 a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/when-should-i-not-kill-9-a-process) to understand why you do not want to use `-9` by default.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the timing, but do you know how I can grab the process id more accurately? I looked at the man-page for pkill, but don't see how I can get the pid. In fact, `pgrep rails` gets nothing, while `ps aux | grep rails` gets the rails server (and chrome too, as you noted).

Comment: It depends on the command line of the server what you need to match. Can you show the output of `ps aux | grep rails`?

Comment: As a guess, the option `-f` could help if rails is not the command name. Try `pgrep -f` or `pgrep -fl`.

Comment: Indeed, the `-f` was the key. Thanks!