# How to kill a process that's not attached to any terminal

Tags: kill, background-process, top, process-management

I'm on an OpenVZ VPS and I created a background process as a non-root user then disowned it i.e.

```
user@server:~$node server.js &
user@server:~$disown
```

I SSH'ed out of the VPS and now I'm back in but I can't seem to kill the process using its PID. `Pkill 1292`. It even fails as root.
I know its not dead because when I run `top` its till running.
Also, when I run `ps -l -p 1292` I can see that the process is till running.

I can tell that the process is not attached to any terminal session because the *ps* command displays a Question Mark at TTY i.e.

[image: screenshot]

How do I kill this process?

Comment: `pkill` is to kill processes based on their name. To kill based on pid, it's just `kill`. If `kill 6806` (short for `kill -s TERM 6806`) fails, you can try `kill -s KILL 6806` which would terminate it non-gracefully.

Comment: Works! Thanks. Used to think pkill meant 'process kill' . Could you post it as an answer so I can mark it as the solution ?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/when-should-i-not-kill-9-a-process;  i am in the kill -9 <pid> camp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pkill` (like `pgrep` which uses the same interface, initially a Solaris command, now found on many other unix-likes including Linux (`procps` package)) is to kill processes based on their name.

```
pkill regexp
```

kills (sends the `SIGTERM` signal) to all the processes whose *name*¹ matches the given regular expression.

So here `pkill node` would kill all the processes whose name contains `node`. Use `pkill -x node` (`-x` like in `grep`/`pgrep` for exact match) to kill processes whose name is *exactly* `node`.

To kill based on pid², it's just `kill` (a command built in most shells so it can also be used on shell jobs, but also as a stand-alone utility).

If `kill 6806` (short for `kill -s TERM 6806`) fails, you can [as a last-resort try `kill -s KILL 6806` which would terminate it non-gracefully](/q/8916).

---

<sup>¹ *process name* being a notion that varies a bit depending on the OS. On Linux, it's generally up to the first 15 bytes of the base name of the file that the process (or its closest ancestor) executed, though a process may change it to any arbitrary (but not longer than 15 bytes) value. See also `pkill -f` to match on the argument list.</sup>

<sup>² `kill` can also kill based on process *group* id. `kill -- -123` sends the SIGTERM signal to all the processes whose process group id is 123. When using the job specification for the `kill` builtin of POSIX shells (as in `kill %spec`), `kill` generally also sends signals to a process *group*.</sup>