# Kill -9 problem in bash file

Tags: shell-script, kill

I wrote a 2 line bash script file in Centos 6.8

```
#! /bin/sh
pid= ps -ef | grep -i 'adminserver' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
kill -9 $pid
```

when I run the script i get the following output:

```
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
```

Comment: pid=$(ps -ef | grep -i 'adminserve[r]' | awk '{print $2}')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pid=` with a space after it would set the `pid` variable to an empty string.  The rest of that line would simply execute the pipeline and output the result (probably to the terminal unless it's being redirected).  Since `$pid` is empty, `kill` later complains.

To capture the output of a command, use `$(...)`, e.g.

```
pid=$( ps -ef | ... )
```

However, it's better to use `pkill` for what you're attempting to do:

```
pkill adminserver
```

See the `pkill` manual.

I would also avoid using the `KILL` signal if at all possible.  See e.g. "[When should I not kill -9 a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/when-should-i-not-kill-9-a-process)".