# Get exit code/signal after a process is completed

Tags: shell, ssh

I run some processes via SSH from a remote client.

Sometimes the processes can be killed, with eg. `kill`. How to get the exit code/signal? The program is a PHP script

I run the script via `sh -c` so I can get the pid and ppid

```
sh -c 'echo $PPID; echo $$; php script.php'
```

Is it possible to listen/get the code from the parent process (`sh -c`)?

I can check if the pid is running, but if it has stopped I don't know if it completed with success, with an error or it was killed

I know you can use `$?` to get the exit code but would that work if the process was killed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sh -c 'echo $PPID; echo $$; php script.php; echo $? > phpexit'; echo $? > shexit
```

The exit code of `php` will be contained in the `phpexit` file.

The exit code of `sh` will be contained in the `shexit` file.

If the `sh` process is killed, the `phpexit` file will not be generated.

You can verify the correctness of each of those by letting the script terminate with success, doing a `pkill php` or killing the PID printed by `echo $$`.

See also [exit codes with special meanings](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html).

Comment: What is the difference between signal 9 and 15?

Comment: @clarkk 9 is KILL (can't be ignored), 15 is TERM (leaves a chance for cleanup by the process). See `man 7 signal` and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8918.

Comment: `SIGKILL` cannot be ignored, caught or blocked. The process will simply die, without being able to do anything about it.

Comment: When I use `kill` I get code `143` ?

Comment: The same goes with `kill -15` gives `143` and if I use `kill -9` I get a bash error.. I don't think I can do anything about that?