# How to redirect the output of a pipe to >/dev/null

Tags: shell, pipe, io-redirection

I would like to redirect the STDOUT and STDERR of the whole pipe to `/dev/null`.

Considering this is my command:

```
sudo lsof -i:22000 -t | xargs kill -9
```

I know this is the wrong way of doing it:

```
sudo lsof -i:22000 -t | xargs kill -9 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

How can we achieve that since simply adding `>/dev/null 2>&1` will not have any effect in the pipe as it will be interpreted as part of the STDIN of `xargs kill -9`?

Comment: I ran a process with PID 32366. `echo 32366 | xargs kill -9 >/dev/null 2>&1` worked for me. This is Bash on Ubuntu 16.

Comment: `(sudo lsof -i:22000 -t | xargs kill -9) >/dev/null 2>&1`?

Comment: @berndbausch If the command to the left of the pipe produced output on standard error, it would appear in the terminal. Try e.g. `{ echo err >&2; echo out; } | cat >/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: @Kusalananda Agreed. I am a sloppy reader and mostly reacted to the remark "will not have any effect in the pipe ...". What about `sudo lsof ... 2>/dev/null | xargs  ... >/dev/null 2>&1`? It's main problem might be more typing than your answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The output from the pipeline

```bsh
sudo lsof -i:22000 -t | xargs kill -9 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

is not fully redirected to `/dev/null` since the redirections at the end are only affecting the `xargs` command, as you noted, leaving the standard error stream of `sudo` connected to the terminal.  The redirections are  however not technically "part of the standard input" of `xargs`.  The standard input of `xargs` comes from the `sudo` command on the left hand side of the pipe.

You will want to redirect the pipeline as a whole:

```bsh
{ your pipeline; } >/dev/null 2>&1
```

i.e.,

```bsh
{ sudo lsof -i:22000 -t | xargs kill -9; } >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Or, you could obviously redirect each individual part individually.

Depending on whether this is a "once-liner" throwaway command that you'll never use again, or a line of code that will go into a system-critical maintenance script, you may want to craft the left-hand side of your pipeline in such a way that it does not produce diagnostic messages at all under normal operating circumstances (and hence does not need to have its error messages hidden).  Alternatively, you may want to manage the service running on port 22000 through systemd or some equivalent service framework.

Tangentially related:

- [When should I not kill -9 a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916)

Comment: This solves so many problems I was having with pipes and that was the only reason I was avoiding using pipes whenever error handling is involved. Thanks a lot!