# how to use awk with echo in bash

Tags: bash, awk, echo

If i run in bash script (similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14669525/8747573)) to send content to a file:

```
sudo ./bar.sh > foo
```

content bar.sh:

```
echo 'for pid in $(ps -ef | grep "smbd" | awk '{print $2}'); do kill -9 $pid &> /dev/null; done'
```

foo out:

```
for pid in $(ps -ef | grep "smbd" | awk {print }); do kill -9 $pid &> /dev/null; done
```

`$2` is lost in out.

expected output:

```
for pid in $(ps -ef | grep "smbd" | awk '{print $2}'); do kill -9 $pid &> /dev/null; done
```

How do I get it?

Comment: Your quoting is strange and looks unbalanced.  What is the point of the echo?

Comment: Don't use single quotes - they prevent shell expansion (as you see).

Comment: It is usually redundant to use awk and grep in the same pipeline.  You can merge the grep into awk.

Comment: What is the final output you are expecting? You are doing things in a very, very complicated way so it isn't clear what you really need here. What should the final output look like? Are you trying to write a script whose output is another script? If you explain what the final objective is, we can help you better.

Comment: I apologize. I wanted to put the complete command to be able to justify the `echo ' '`

Comment: you can post the full answer, to review it and select it if it works. Thanks

Comment: OK. Please just add the output you are expecting. What do you want `foo` to contain?

Comment: @terdon update with expected output:

Comment: What's the point of a having a script (`bar.sh`) if it only outputs a fixed string? You could just put that string in a file and run `cat bar.txt > foo` instead. Or just edit it into `foo` directly.

Comment: This I posted is just a snippet of the script (the part of the problem). I can't change it because "foo" is actually a script to which many commands are added depending on what the user wants, and it is programmed in crontab. So I can't change it. I just need to fix the published part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, ***never run things with `sudo` unless it is actually necessary to run them with `sudo`***. I really cannot emphasize that enough. Unless you get a "permission denied" error, you don't need `sudo` and you should not use `sudo`. So you don't need `sudo ./bar.sh`, just run `./bar.sh`.

Next, you don't need to `echo` to get the results of a command. This isn't needed:

```
echo '$(ps -ef | grep "smbd" | awk '{print $2}')'
```

All you need is to run the command itself. You don't need the command substitution (`$(command)`) or the echo. Just have this in your script:

```
ps -ef | grep "smbd" | awk '{print $2}'
```

Note that if you want to get the PID of a running process, you don't really want `ps` either. You can just use `pgrep smbd` which avoids the problem of the `grep` process itself appearing in the results.

Finally, if you want to print a multi-line string as output, you can use a [here doc](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) instead of many echo statements. So, putting all that together, you should make `bar.sh` like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat <<'EoF'
for pid in $(ps -ef | grep "smbd" | awk '{print $2}'); do 
    kill -9 "$pid" &> /dev/null
done
EoF
```

And then run it as `./bar.sh > foo` (no `sudo`!).

Or, here's a simpler version of the same approach:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat <<'EoF'
ps -ef | awk '/smbd/{print $2}' | while read pid; do 
    kill -9 "$pid" &> /dev/null
done
EoF
```

Or, even simpler:

```
#!/bin/sh

printf '%s\n' 'kill -9 $(pgrep smbd)'
```

Which brings us to the final point of are you *sure* you really want a script for this? To kill all running `smbd` processes, all you need is a single command:

```
pkill -9 smbd
```

Comment: `<<'EoF'` or so if you want the here-doc passed as-is. (Not that I still understand what the point of the whole exercise is.)

Comment: Of course, thanks @ilkkachu. And no, I don't really see the point either but there may be a special need we're not aware of.

Comment: @ajcg how does this not fix what you posted? Just use the here string approach and you can print whatever you want. The first example I give should produce exactly the output you are looking for.

Comment: `cat <<'EoF'` It is not the answer I was looking for, but it solves my problem. Thanks

Comment: @ajcg the answer you were looking for is this: `echo 'for pid in $(ps -ef | grep "smbd" | awk '{print \$2}'); do kill -9 $pid &> /dev/null; done'`. You need to escape the `$2` with `\$2`. But use the heredoc instead it is easier and more powerful.

Comment: @terdon yeah that was what I was looking for. Great job. Thank you. Both solutions fix the problem

Comment: Unless there's a really good reason, the `-9` is not needed. See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916