# Strange mysqld process on my system wont let port 3306 be free

Tags: ssh, background-process, port-forwarding

I am using ubuntu Jammy release and on my system port no 3306 is unusable since I tried ssh based port forwarding on the same to a different machine. Also while running `ps -aux` it shows a strage process for mysqld with pid 2336 which I havent installed locally.

It doesnt allow me to kill the process as normal user. When I kill with sudo it simply restarts this process again. Even on machine restart this process shows up on its own.

It seems to me that this process is started by SSH deamon. One reason I think so is absence of process path in the last column. Any ideas how I can stop this ?

[image]

Comment: Looks like Mysql or Mariadb is installed, plus mysql-workbench. Before you remove these, consider that they might have been installed as part of software that requires database services. Nothing in your output indicates that SSH is involved.

Comment: the `systemd+` in the first column suggests it's `systemd` that is starting that process and keeping ti going after you kill it ... `systemctl status mysqld` may shed some light on your lack of understanding

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Comment: there was no easy way to copy the whole thing @Kusalananda

Comment: @JaromandaX as I mentioned there is no local mysqld installation. I use mysqlworkbench and connect to remote mysql server or local docker based installations. So as expected  `systemctl status mysqld`  throws message  `Unit mysqld.service could not be found.`

Comment: the service may not be called `mysqld.service` ... that was a guess on my part ... I would bet that it is *some* systemd service though - pretty easy to find out what service it is though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, you have MySQL installed and running.  This may have been done without you noticing, for example I believe some local file indexing on Ubuntu uses it.

Find the installed systemd units:

```
systemctl list-unit-files | grep -e maria -e MySQL
```

Find what process is actually keeping the file open:

```
netstat -antpl |grep "3306.*LISTEN"
```

Look for MySQL config:

```
ls /etc/my.cnf
```

```
grep include /etc/my.cnf
```

On a side note:  Don't use `kill -9` unless you have no other way to do it.  SigKILL should never ever ever be your *default*. See also [When should I not kill -9 a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916)

Comment: Your pointers are helpful. Running netstat showed a docker proxy instance that was occupying the port and stopping and removing the container  fixed the problem.

Comment: Interestingly I did think about containers briefly but dismissed the idea.