# How do I force a user to log out?

Tags: administration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you kick a benign user off your system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/615/how-do-you-kick-a-benign-user-off-your-system)

I'm trying to remove a user account with the `userdel -r` command. However, it says that it is unable to remove the user because they are still signed in - even if I boot the machine without explicitly using that account it still says this. I've tried using `sudo pkill -KILL -u` but with no success. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can force it with `-f`. But you should probably find out why and how they are logged in first, or you may leave your system in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the  -f option to forcefully delete the user.

```
userdel -rf
```